# Vidyo : Seeing a Black Screen in Mobile during a video call

Tags: vidyo

I am using **Vidyo** SDK(android) for video communication. We make video communications from mobile to Web application(Both using Vidyo SDK).

Sometimes during a call, web Video is not rendering on the mobile application, instead, a black is popping up(see below image)

[image]

TIA